# How can I run MapReduce ToolRunner jobs with Oozie?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I developed a MapReduce application which uses `ToolRunner`. Based on the arguments and configuration properties passed by the user the application sets up the job in a certain way: chooses a particular input/output format, chooses the mapper and reducer classes etc.. This logic is implemented in the `run(String[] args)` method from my main class, which implements `Configured` and `Tool`.

Oozie supports MapReduce action nodes, but the problem is that I can't use them with my custom `ToolRunner` application. The MapReduce action only allows to define a static job by configuring input/output formats, mapper/reducer classes and key/value classes. My application does this dynamically based on the higher level business logic.

The action should be able to execute something like this command line:

```
hadoop jar my.jar com.example.MyMainClass -D my.config1=a -D my.config2=b arg1 arg2
```

Can I create Oozie actions which support `ToolRunner` MapReduce applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [Java Action](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action).  It is, unfortunately, not ideal because Oozie creates a job to then run your `ToolRunner` which creates it's own job(s).  It does work though.

Comment: Based on your answer I read more about Java Actions and find out that they run from a mapper, exactly like Shell Actions. Are Pig and Hive actions started from a mapper as well?

Comment: Good question.  I haven't tried Pig or Hive actions, so I don't know what they do.  I wouldn't be surprised though.